If $21(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = (x + 2y + 4z)^2$, then $x$, $y$ , $z$ are in A.P., G.P. or H.P.?
If $21(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = (x + 2y + 4z)^2$, then $x$, $y$ , $z$ are in A.P., G.P. or H.P. (arithmetic progression, geometric progression, harmonic progression) ?

I'm looking for better approaches . (Kinda a.m.-g.m. inequality ones or maybe Lagrange identity)

My try
$$21(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = (x + 2y + 4z)^2$$
$$=> 20x^2 + 17y^2 + 5z^2 = 4xy + 16yz + 8xz$$
$$ => 4x^2 - 4xy + y^2 + 16y^2 - 16yz + 4z^2 + z^2 - 8xz + 16x^2 = 0$$
$$ => (2x-y)^2 + (4y-2z)^2 + (z-4x)^2 = 0$$
$$ => y = 2x, 2y = z, z = 4x $$
$ => x, y, z$ i.e., $x, 2x, 4x$ are in G.P.

What are A.P, G.P, or H.P? Please answer this even if you are already satisfied w the answers below, as the question/answer is not just for you but for whoever looks at this and is interested. Thanks!

I think it is arithmetic progression, geometric progression, harmonic progression.

Just another approach:
$$(1+4+16)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geqslant (x+2y+4z)^2$$
by CS inequality. Using the equality condition for CS, we need $x:y:z=1:2:4$ for the equation to be true.

You mastered Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, excellent solution! +1

Absolutely I was looking exactly for this one

Same outcome,
$$  20 \left( x - \frac{y}{10} - \frac{z}{5} \right)^2 + \frac{84}{5}  \left( y - \frac{z}{2} \right)^2  $$
must be zero. So $z = 2y.$  Next $y = 2x.$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 10 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 84 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 10 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 & 17 &  - 8 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 8 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
